# Question about Zeta Function of Singular Plane Curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am working on a project which involves learning about the zeta function (weil zeta function) for plane curves, but I do not know much algebraic geometry. (I do not know anything about schemes).

I am mostly interested in irreducible projective plane curves $C$ over finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$. We define the zeta function by

$$Z(C, t) = \exp\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n = 1}{\frac{\# C(\mathbb{F}_{q^n})}{n} t^n}\right)$$

My supervisor has told me some facts about the zeta function for plane curves, and I am seeking a reference for these facts. I would also like to  know under what conditions these facts hold true, in particular whether they are still true even when the curve is *singular*, or if they are still true if the curve is an affine plane curve.

The facts I want information about are:

1. For a plane curve $C \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$ given by $f(x,y) = 0$ with $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[x,y]$, the zeta function $Z(C,t)$ is rational. Also, for a plane curve $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$, $Z(C,t)$ is rational.
2. $Z(C,t) = \frac{f(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)}$, i.e. the denominator has the form $g(t) = (1-t)(1-qt)$. My understanding is that this the case for irreducible projective plane curves, whether or not the curve is singular or non-singular. Is this also true for affine plane curves?

EDIT: I have phrased (2) incorrectly. What I want to know is if $Z(C,t)$ can be *written* in the form $\frac{f(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)}$ where $f(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$, or more precisely, if it is true that $$Z(C,t) = \frac{f(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)} (1-t)^i$$ for some $i \geq 0$. Is there anywhere I can find a reference for this?

3. When the (irreducible projective plane) curve is *non-singular*, we have $f(t) = 1 + a_1 t + \dots + a_g t^g + q a_{g-1} t^{g+1} + \dots + q^g t^{2g}$. My understanding is that this is not the case when the curve is *singular*.

Comment: I would have prefered this to be a comment.
This text contains what you want, if you are comfortable with french. [here](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/xups/xups12-02.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a singular curve $C$, you have a compactification $\overline{C}$ and a normalization $\tilde{C}$. Over a perfect field, such as a finite field, the normalization is smooth (and projective).

The best way to study the zeta function of $C$ is by studying the zeta function of $\tilde{C}$ and then adding additional factors to get to the zeta function of $C$.

Using the product formula for the zeta function, the zeta function of $\overline{C}$ is equal to the zeta function of $C$ times one factor of $(1-t^d)^{-1}$ for each degree $d$ point added to make the compactification. To go from the zeta function of $\overline{C}$ to the zeta function of $\tilde{C}$, we remove the factor of $(1-t^d)^{-1}$ for each singular point of degree $d$ and then add back in a factor of $(1-t^e)^{-1}$ for each degree $e$ point lying over it. Because $e$ is always a multiple of $d$, and there is always at least one point, $(1-t^d)$ always divides $(1-t^e)$. In other words, the zeta function of $C$ is the zeta function of $\tilde{C}$ times a polynomial, as you suspect.

However, this polynomial need not always have roots only at one. Instead, they can be arbitrary roots of unity. So we have

$$Z(C,t) = \frac{ f(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)} \prod_{i=1}^n (1- \zeta_i t) $$

where $f(t)$ satisfies the symmetry property you state and $\zeta_i$ are some roots of unity.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anywhere you know of that I can learn these facts from? Do you know where I can learn about normalisation and compactification, particularly over finite fields and/or fields which are not algebraically closed? 

I have not been able to find the information you provided anywhere else. Do you know of any resources which contain this information?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the compactification of a curve the same as the "projective closure"? Or is it a different thing?

Comment: @maddels Yes, compactification is the same as the projective closure. (technically there may be more than one compactification, of which a projective closure is just one example, but only one compactification is needed for this anyways.)

Comment: Would you be willing to direct me to some resources where I can learn about algebraic curves over finite fields and zeta functions? I am an undergraduate in Australia, and I am struggling to find the information you provided elsewhere, as well as the algebraic geometry I need to know for this project at level that is accessible to me. I would appreciate anything you could point me to look at.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @maddels I don't know a great answer to your question. It seems likely that the book Algebraic Curves over a Finite Field  by Hirschfeld, Korchmaros, and Torres contains a lot of helpful information as it is long and focused on concrete problems. http://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1287kdw

Comment: @maddels Another idea is you could find a reference you like that handles algebraic curves over algebraically closed fields and try yourself to translate it to the setting of a non-algebraically closed field. Once you have the idea to use prime ideals instead of points, many things are quite similar.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Will. I will try to study the algebraically closed case and translate, as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

1. is a general fact for varieties, proved by Dwork. For curves, you argue directly, since there exists a smooth projective curve $C'$ and open sets $U \subset C, U' \subset C'$ with $U,U'$ isomorphic. Then 
   $$Z(C,T)=Z(U,T)Z(C-U,T)=Z(C',T)Z(C-U,T)/Z(C'-U',T)$$
   and the zeta functions of the zero dimensional schemes $C-U,C'-U'$ are easy to control.
2. and 3. are not correct if the hypotheses are removed.

Try the examples of projective curves $y^2=x^3+x^2, y^2=x^3+ax^2$, with $a$ a non-square and of the affine line.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I computed the zeta function of $y^2=x^3+x^2$ and $y^2=x^3+ax^2$ when $q=p=5$. I computed $Z(t)=\frac{1}{1−5t}$ for the former, and with $a=3$, I computed $Z(t)=\frac{1+t}{(1-t)(1−5t)}$ for the latter. I would like to rewrite/modify my second claim. The claim should instead be: $Z(C,t)$ can be written as $\frac{f(t)}{(1−t)(1−qt)}$ with $f(t)\in\mathbb{Z}[t]$. Or, more precisely, $\frac{f(t)}{(1−t)(1−qt)}(1-t)^i$ for some i. (So some factors of $(1-t)$ may cancel). The examples you have suggested I try are okay under this claim.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me if the modified claim is true? Is there anywhere I could find a reference for it?